# How can you save attachments in mails of Gmail to Gdocs?

Tags: email, gmail, google-docs

**Problem:** to extract many pdf-attachments in Gmail to my Google Docs, and labeling each file by "Python".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is this:

Use wireshark with the filter **tcp port 80** and do your task a few times manually. Then examine the requests made by your browser in Wireshark.

Then build the script using the **httplib** module to automate the previously examined requests.

As I know there is a "View as HTML" link in gmail when you receive a PDF attachment. You can use that to convert the documents to google docs.

Comment: Note that this won't be an easy task, however.

Comment: Also note that "view as HTML" isn't a very robust feature of GMail yet and tends to strip off most of the formatting in PDFs. Try this manually and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Any solution to this would be non-trivial and require programmatically reading your mail, iterating through the attachments, cracking the PDFs, opening Google docs, and transcribing the contents of one into the other. I doubt there's any pre-packaged functionality for any of that in the Google APIs, extensive though they may be.

Answer (score 1):

Mailspect offers this, http://esm.mailspect.com/index.php/Attachments_as_Google_Docs